# Modified Bubble Sort

Tags: java, runtime, bubble-sort

I need to write an algorithm that will take an array of ints and find the k'th largest element in the array. The caveat here is that the runtime must be O(K*n) or better.

My teacher has made it clear this can be done with a modified bubble sort program, but I am unsure as to how I can modify the bubble sort without ruining it, as I would think it necessary to loop through every element of the array. Here is my code (just the shell of the program and an unmodified bubble sort):

```
public int kthLargest(int[] A, int k){

    int[] sorted = A;
    int temp;
    for (int i = (A.length - 1); i >= 0; i--)
       {
          for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
          {
             if (sorted[j-1] < sorted[j])
             {
                  temp = sorted[j-1];
                  sorted[j-1] = sorted[j];
                  sorted[j] = temp;
             }
          }
       }
    return sorted[k-1];
}
```

Figured it out:

```
public int kthLargest(int[] A, int k){

    int[] sorted = A;
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length-1; i++)
       {
          for (int j = 0; j < A.length-i-1; j++)
          {
             if (sorted[j] > sorted[j+1])
             {
                  temp = sorted[j];
                  sorted[j] = sorted[j+1];
                  sorted[j+1] = temp;
             }
             if(i == (k-1)) return A[A.length-i-1];
          }
       }
    return sorted[A.length-k];
```

}

The the array has been sorted to the k-th largest element, it has found what it is looking for and can stop the sort and return.

Comment: Normal bubble sort and then slice off the kth? :)

Comment: so stop the sort after i=k?

Comment: It's pretty simple, just change (A.length - 1) to (k - 1)

Comment: ASKASK- tried it, didn't work. I see what you were going for, that solution would limit the sorting to the part of the array below the k'th element, so any higher valued int's >= k will be left out of the sorting

Answer (score 0):

I thought a modified bubble sort just exited early if the list was already sorted?

Wouldn't something like this suffice?

```
public int kthLargest(int[] A, int k){
    int[] sorted = A;
    int temp;
    bool bSorted = TRUE;
    for (int i = (A.length - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
      for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
      {
         if (sorted[j-1] < sorted[j])
         {
              temp = sorted[j-1];
              sorted[j-1] = sorted[j];
              sorted[j] = temp;
              bSorted = FALSE;
         }
      }
      if(bSorted)
          break;
   }
   return sorted[k-1];
}
```

Comment: The key is to stop sorting after the k-th position of the array has been sorted, as that is the number we are looking for. to sort the entire array would be terribly time consuming if, say, we have an array of 1000000 elements